# How to iterate over RecyclerView items

Tags: android-recyclerview

In my app i have a RecyclerView with a simple item view that consists of a TextView and a Spinner in each row.

After the user clicks "Save" from the action bar, i need to iterate over all the items and get the Spinner selected value.

Any ideas how this can or should be achieved?

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to iterate using the following loop, but is it a good solution calling findViewById() for every row since it's a heavy function to call performance wise?

```
for (int i = 0; i < rvAttendanceItems.getChildCount(); i++) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rvAttendanceItems.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendance_list_status);
    spinner.getSelectedItemId();
}
```

My full RecyclerView code:

```
public class AttendanceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttendanceAdapter.AttendanceViewHolder> {

    private List<Student> studentItems;
    private Fragment frag;
    ArrayList<Status> statuses = new ArrayList<>();

    public AttendanceAdapter(List<Student> studentItems, Fragment frag) {
        this.studentItems = studentItems;
        this.frag = frag;

        DbHelper db = DbHelper.getInstance(frag.getContext());
        Cursor c = db.getStatuses("attendance");

        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Status tempStatus = new Status(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.STATUS_ID)), c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.STATUS_COLOR)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.STATUS_DESC)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.STATUS_CATEGORY)));
                statuses.add(tempStatus);
            }
            c.close();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(frag.getContext(), "Could not retrieve status list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AttendanceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_attendance, parent, false);
        return new AttendanceViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AttendanceViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Student current = studentItems.get(position);

        SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(frag.getContext(), R.layout.item_spinner_status, statuses);

        holder.sStatus.setAdapter(adapter);
        holder.tvName.setText(current.getFullName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return studentItems.size();
    }

    public class AttendanceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView tvName;
        private final Spinner sStatus;

        public AttendanceViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendance_list_name);
            sStatus = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendance_list_status);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    sStatus.performClick();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want the value of `sStatus ` after clicking save ?

Comment: Yes, but i need the value of sStatus for all RecyclerView items. so if i have 10 rows, i need to loop them and get the value of sStatus for all

Comment: Can you post the whole Recycler-View-code?

Comment: I have added the whole code

Comment: You could add an `ArrayList<Spinner>` to your `AttendanceAdapter` and add the Spinners to the ArrayList in the constructor of `AttendanceViewHolder`. Then you can iterate over all spinners after a button click. An other way would be the `getChildAt()` method of recyclerview.

Answer (score 11):

You already made the call to `findViewById()` in the view holder and don't need to make it again:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rvAttendanceItems.getChildCount(); i++) {
    AttendanceViewHolder holder = (AttendanceViewHolder) rv.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
    holder.sStatus.getSelectedItemId();
}
```

Comment: getChildCount() can return only the items which are viewable on the screen. a better solution is to use the adapter to get the count.